# Cmake can't find Qt OpenGL library

Tags: qt, opengl, qt4, cmake

I'm trying to compile a project using `cmake`. The instructions given to me was that Qt 4.8 is needed. Downloaded it from [qt-project.org/downloads](http://qt-project.org/downloads). Compiled and installed Qt 4.8:

```
mazdak@lnxamindai> qmake -query   
QT_INSTALL_PREFIX:/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5
QT_INSTALL_DATA:/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5
QT_INSTALL_DOCS:/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/doc
QT_INSTALL_HEADERS:/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/include
QT_INSTALL_LIBS:/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/lib
QT_INSTALL_BINS:/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/bin
QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS:/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/plugins
QT_INSTALL_IMPORTS:/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/imports
QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS:/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/translations
QT_INSTALL_CONFIGURATION:/etc/xdg
QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES:/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/examples
QT_INSTALL_DEMOS:/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/demos
QMAKE_MKSPECS:/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/mkspecs
QMAKE_VERSION:2.01a
QT_VERSION:4.8.5
```

However, when compiling the project I received the following error:

```
root@lnxamindai> cmake .    
    -- Setting flags for GNU GCC
    -- REQUIRED_VARS  (missing:  QTMOBILITY_INCLUDE_DIR QTMOBILITY_MULTIMEDIAKIT_INCLUDE_DIR QTMOBILITY_MULTIMEDIAKIT_LIBRARY VERSION_VAR QTMOBILITY_VERSION)
    Qt QTOPENGL library not found.
    -- Buiding ManyEarsLib Library...
    -- Buiding RTAudio Library...
    -- Found jack: /usr/lib/libjack.so
    ALSA lib : -lasound -lpthread
    Qt QTOPENGL library not found.
    CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
    Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
    OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
       used as include directory in directory /home/mazdak/dev/ManyEars/manyears/QtGUI
    QTMOBILITY_MULTIMEDIAKIT_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
        linked by target "ManyEars" in directory /home/mazdak/dev/ManyEars/manyears/QtGUI

    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
(...)

IF (NOT MANYEARS_GUI_DISABLED)

    SET(QT_USE_QTNETWORK TRUE)
    SET(QT_USE_QTSVG TRUE)
    SET(QT_USE_QTXML TRUE)
    SET(QT_USE_QTSCRIPT TRUE)
    SET(QT_USE_QTOPENGL TRUE)
    SET(QT_USE_QTMULTIMEDIA TRUE)

    find_package(QtMobility COMPONENTS MultimediaKit)
    find_package(Qt4 4.8.0 QUIET)

    if (QTMOBILITY_FOUND)
        MESSAGE("QT_MOBILITY_INCLUDE_DIR : ${QTMOBILITY_INCLUDE_DIRS} QT_MOBILITY_LIB: ${QTMOBILITY_LIBRARIES}")
    ENDIF (QTMOBILITY_FOUND)


    if(QT4_FOUND AND (QT_QTMULTIMEDIA_FOUND OR QTMOBILITY_FOUND))
    include(${QT_USE_FILE})
    else(QT4_FOUND AND (QT_QTMULTIMEDIA_FOUND OR QTMOBILITY_FOUND))
        MESSAGE("WARNING : ManyEars GUI will not be compiled because Qt4 not found or obsolete. You need Qt 4.8 or higher.Try using the latest QtSDK from http://qt-project.org")
        MESSAGE("DEBUG: QT4_FOUND: ${QT4_FOUND} QT_MULTIMEDIA_FOUND: ${QT_QTMULTIMEDIA_FOUND}  QT_MOBILITY_FOUND: ${QTMOBILITY_FOUND}")
        SET(MANYEARS_GUI_DISABLED TRUE)
    endif(QT4_FOUND AND (QT_QTMULTIMEDIA_FOUND OR QTMOBILITY_FOUND))

ELSE (NOT MANYEARS_GUI_DISABLED)
    MESSAGE("ManyEars GUI disabled.")
ENDIF (NOT MANYEARS_GUI_DISABLED)


#Files excluded from package
set(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES
  "build"
  "bin"
  ${CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES}
  ".svn"
)



#include files
(...)

IF (UNIX)

        #########################################
        # Packaging stuff for sources (All UNIX)
        #########################################
        SET(CPACK_SOURCE_GENERATOR "TGZ")
            SET(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/COPYING.TXT")
        SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "ManyEars")
        SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "ManyEars")
        SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "Francois Grondin, Dominic Letourneau")
            SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/README.TXT")
        SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT "blablablabla")


    (...)

ENDIF(UNIX)

(...)

INCLUDE(CPack)
```

This is confusing me, shouldn't the OpenGL library be installed?

Comment: Please provide a self-contained example, not a bloated like this. sscce.org. Also, I do not understand why you use OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED) when you should only use QT_INCLUDES.

Comment: Why didn't you simply install the Qt library and development files using your Linux distribution's package manager?

Comment: @datenwolf Because the version in the linux distribution was 4.6 and I needed 4.8 or higher.

Comment: @LaszloPapp It's not an example, this is the issue. Since I haven't got any experience using Qt, the given information is not stripped.  
The GUI is built in Qt, which is why I was struck with this issue. Also the cmake file is not written by me, I'm just interpreting it. Trying to test the project.

Comment: @Mazze: well, you need to put a minimal effort into this so that we can help you further. Currently, it is a bloated stuff.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I actually am putting a lot of effort into it, but with little or no feedback I can't do much more. I'm really trying to solve the issue here. If you need more information, then just tell me instead of mocking.

Comment: I already did: sscce.org. Read it, provide a minimal example reproducing the issue.

Comment: @LaszloPapp It is as short as it can be due to the fact that I have no/very little prior knowledge. Which automatically responds to the second "s" which it actually is. The output was posted and analyzed in the question marked in bold text further down. "correct", well perhaps the line length is annoying. Lastly the problem I'm solving is described in the first couple of sentences. Do you need further information or?

Comment: @Mazze: why are you defending yourself? I asked some effort after which I am willing to help. If you cannot do that for some reason, no problem. I will not be angry or unhappy. You will not get help from me, that is all. Others might have the sake to help like datenwolf, etc.

Comment: @Mazze Don't worry about him; he comes across as rather... harsh (you can read his past comments on his page to realize that this is always his tone so you shouldn't feel targeted). What he was asking for was for you to remove all the parts in the `CMakeLists.txt` that did not relate to QT.

Comment: @SethMMorton Alrighty, thanks for the input, I'll edit the post

Comment: @SethMMorton: please do not motivate others not to put some minimal effort into a question if I may ask. You can say for many people "rather ... harsh", but it is not helpful. Many-many people, including me, asking for sscce.org compliant questions to be able to help, otherwise it is really difficult to do so. Some people consider it a harsh thing not to provide better information to the people who are spending their free time to be able to help, IMO.

Comment: As it seems, a few lines would have been enough to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I was not motivating him to put in minimal effort (as you can read in my comment, I advised him to remove the extra stuff from the post as just as you were asking).  You have definitely misinterpreted my comment, because I agreed with your sentiment.  I often direct people to SSCCE.org as well.  I was only commenting on the tone of your comments; perhaps if you chose your wordings a little more carefully people wouldn't be so defensive.  To use an old adage, "You can catch more flies with honey than with vinegar."

Comment: @SethMMorton: You said "all the parts not related to Qt". That is not true, even parts that are related to Qt, but unrelated to the QtOpenGL issue at hand. Thereby, I still do not agree about your post, and encouragement to post more than needed. ;-) Well, to me, it seems that you accuse me with misunderstanding your post rather than assuming that I may have a different opinion than yours. That is not careful wording in my book, and I could also say harsh, but why not concentrate on the techical side rather than qualifying personalities on a technical site?

Comment: @LaszloPapp Only because you asked the OP "why are you defending yourself?"  If the OP felt defensive by your questions, then they might not want to post more to clarify, frustrating both parties.  I'm just not sure that it's necessary on a friendly site (even if it is technical) to be aggressive.  Having said this, I am explicitly stating that I will not comment on this further than you, so you are free to have the last word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is confusing me, shouldn't the OpenGL library be installed?

It's not complaining about OpenGL. It's complainting about Qt's OpenGL module QtOpenGL which is a different thing. Most likely your custom build of Qt doesn't include the QtOpenGL module. You've to go back building Qt and take extra care that you enable build of the QtOpenGL module.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found out that [I needed to install some development packages if I was compiling from the source code](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/requirements-x11.html).

```
apt-get install libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libx11-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxi-dev libxrender-dev libxcb1-dev libx11-xcb-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-keysyms1-dev libxcb-image0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-icccm4-dev libxcb-sync0-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-render-util0-dev
```

When configuring the Qt source code I had forgot to specify that I wanted to install the OpenGL module and the Multimedia Kit. I just naturally ran "configure" without any options and hoped for the best.

```
./configure --help
```

Specifies that I needed `-multimedia` and `-opengl`.
When I executed configure with the correct options the issue was resolved.

```
./configure -multimedia -opengl
```

Note that the multimedia kit needs gstreamer installed.

Comment: The gstreamer dependency is for Phonon. But there are other viable Phonon-Backends as well, like VLC. Still gstreamer is probably the best option.

Comment: @Mazze So you need to build with -multimedia as well (not just -opengl) to fix the "Cmake can't find Qt OpenGL library"?